# Calculadora Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou criando uma calculadora clone igual do iPhone, até a parte de digitar o primeiro valor da operação está ok, o problema é quando eu vou pra segunda parte (depois de escolher um operador, como +, -, /, *), eu preciso que pare de adicionar na variável valor1 e comece adicionar na variável de valor2, como faz isso?

```js
let visor = document.querySelector(".calculadora__visor");
let calcular = document.querySelector(".calculadora__botao_cal");
let ac = document.querySelector(".calculadora__botao-AC");

let firstCLick = true
let secondClick = false
let valor1 = []
let valor2 = []
let operacao = []

for (let btn = 0; btn <= 9; btn++) {
  let botao = document.querySelector(`.calculadora__botao${btn}`)
  botao.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (firstCLick) {
      visor.textContent = ""
      firstCLick = false
    }
    valor1 = visor.textContent += btn;
    for (let op = 1; op <= 4; op++) {
      let operador = document.querySelector(`.botao__op${op}`)
      operador.addEventListener("click", () => {
        visor.textContent = ""
        if (secondClick === false) {
          valor2 = visor.textContent += btn
        }
      })
    }
  })
}

ac.addEventListener("click", () => {
  firstCLick = true
  visor.textContent = 0
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Calculadora</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="calculadora">
    <span class="calculadora__visor">0</span>
    <div class="container__calculadora">
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao-AC">AC</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao-mais-menos">+/-</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao-porc">%</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao-div botao__op4">/</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao7">7</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao8">8</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao9">9</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao-x botao__op3">x</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao4">4</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao5">5</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao6">6</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao-menos botao__op2">-</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao1">1</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao2">2</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao3">3</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao_somar botao__op1">+</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao0">0</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao3">,</button>
      <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao_cal">=</button>
      <!-- <button class="calculadora__botao calculadora__botao_del">⌫</button> -->
    </div>
  </main>
  <!-- script src="./cal.js"></script -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Adicione a parte do HTML também. Vá em [edit] a pergunta e pressione Ctrl+M

Answer (score -3):

1 - Inicialize as variáveis valor1, valor2 e operador com valores padrão. Por exemplo, valor1 = 0, valor2 = null e operador = null.

2 - Ao digitar um número, verifique o estado atual do operador:

3 - Se operador for null, significa que você ainda está na fase de entrada do primeiro valor da operação. Nesse caso, adicione o número digitado à variável valor1.

- Se operador não for null, isso significa que você já selecionou um operador e está na fase de entrada do segundo valor da operação. Nesse caso, adicione o número digitado à variável valor2.
- Quando o usuário selecionar um operador, atualize a variável operador com o operador escolhido.

4 - Ao realizar a operação matemática, verifique se valor1 e valor2 são válidos (ou seja, diferentes de null). Se ambos forem válidos, execute a operação desejada (por exemplo, adição, subtração, multiplicação ou divisão) usando os valores de valor1 e valor2. O resultado pode ser armazenado novamente em valor1 para continuar a operação, se necessário.

Essa abordagem permite que você alterne entre a entrada de valor1 e valor2 com base no estado do operador. Dessa forma, você pode separar as entradas dos dois valores e realizar a operação matemática correta.

Comment: cara, você me ajudou muito!!!

Eu estava "quase no caminho certo", tenho que treinar minha lógica...
Mas muito obrigado!!!!